# Реализация обратной связи через бота

Tags: python, telebot

Без понятия правильно ли я сформулировал заголовок, но есть бот, нужно сделать так чтобы: пользователь отправил сообщение, бот исполнил команду в консоли, и отправил сообщением вывод команды

Comment: так а проблема где?

Comment: проблема в том что я незнаю как достать вывод и отправить сообщением

Answer (score 1):

на примере выполнения команды `lpstat -t` на удалённой машине (Ubuntu) средствами `paramiko`:

```
def lpstat(message):
    connect(message, 'lpstat -t', '0')

def connect(message, command, name):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    data = ''

    client.connect(hostname='ip', username=user, password=password, port=22)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    data = stdout.read().decode('utf-8').strip('\n')
    client.close()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(data))
```

на примере перезапуска `spooler` на удалённой машине (Windows Server) средствами `winrm`:

```
def spooler_restart(server):
    s = winrm.Session(server, auth=(ad_user, ad_pass), transport='ntlm')
    stop = s.run_cmd('net stop spooler')
    status_stop = stop.std_out.translate(None, b'\r\n').decode('cp866').replace('The ', '').replace('.', '\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    start = s.run_cmd('net start spooler')
    status_start = start.std_out.translate(None, b'\r\n').decode('cp866').replace('The ', '').replace('.', '\n')

    if 'stopped successfully' in status_stop and 'started successfully' in status_start:
        return str(stop.status_code) + ', Служба успешно остановлена\n' + \
               str(start.status_code) + ', Служба успешно запущена'
    else:
        return str(stop.status_code) + str(start.status_code)
```